# $[F]_p\le [f]_1[g]_p$ for $1\le p\le\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> For real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ on $(0,\infty)$, let 
>   $$F(x)=\int_0^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)g(y)\frac{dy}{y}$$
>   If $1\le p\le\infty$, set $$[h]_p=\left(\int_0^\infty |h(x)|^p\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{1/p}$$ and for $p=\infty$, define $[h]_\infty=\operatorname{ess sup}|h|.$ Prove that for $1\le p\le\infty$, $[F]_p\le [f]_1[g]_p$.

---

My attempt:

Note that when $p\ne\infty$
\begin{align}
[F]_p&\le\left(\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty \left|f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)g(y)\right|\frac{dy}{y}\right)^p\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{1/p}\\
&\le \left(\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{g(y)}{y^{1/p}}\frac{f(\frac{x}{y})}{y^{1/q}}\right|dy\right)^p\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{1/p}\\
&\le [g]_p \left(\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty \left|f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right|^q\frac{dy}{y}\right)^{p/q}\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{1/p}
\end{align}
where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and the second inequality is by Holder's inequality. Now it suffices to show that $$ \left(\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty \left|f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right|^q\frac{dy}{y}\right)^{p/q}\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{1/p}\le\int_0^\infty |f(x)|\frac{dx}{x} $$ but I get stuck.

Comment: This is just convolution with respect to Haar measure on the multiplicative group of positive reals. You can use a logarithmic change of coordinates to turn it into ordinary convolution and then just use young’s convolution inequality, with p=r and q=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minkowski's integral inequality will be more helpful. First note that via the transformation $x\mapsto \dfrac{x}{y}$, $$F(x) = \int_0^\infty f(y)\,g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\,\frac{dy}{y}$$ Let $\mu$ be the measure on $(0, \infty)$ such that $d\mu(x) = \dfrac{dx}{x}$. For $p \neq \infty$, Minkowski's inequality gives
$$[F]_p = \|F\|_{L^p(\mu)}\le \int_0^\infty \left\lVert f(y)\, g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \right\rVert_{L^p_x(\mu)}\, d\mu(y)$$ where the last bound can be written 
$$\int_0^\infty \lvert f(y)\rvert\, \left\lVert g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right\rVert_{L_x^p(\mu)}\, d\mu(y) = \int_0^\infty \lvert f(y)\rvert \|g(x)\|_{L_x^p(\mu)}\, d\mu(y) = [f]_1[g]_p$$ 
If $p = \infty$, then for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, $\lvert F(x)\rvert \le \int_0^\infty \lvert f(y)\rvert [g]_\infty d\mu(y) = [f]_1[g]_\infty$ Hence, $[F]_\infty \le [f]_1[g]_\infty$.

Comment: Nice! Actually, the Minkowski's integral inequality is also true for $p=\infty$, so we don't need to discuss when $p=\infty$.

Comment: @user549397 true, except $[F]_{\infty}$, being $\|F\|_{L^{\infty}(dx)}$, is not necessarily the same as $\|F\|_{L^{\infty}(\mu)}$.

Comment: Aha! I see, thank you.